# Getting 'mismatching null constraints' error when implementing Map.entrySet (Java8, Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, nullable, non-nullable

I get the error...

```
The return type is incompatible with 'Set<Map.Entry<K,T>>' returned from Map<K,T>.entrySet() (mismatching null constraints)
```

...when implementing a `Map` and overriding `Map.entrySet` like this:

```
package org.abego.util;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
...    
public abstract class MyMap<K, T> implements Map<K, T> {
    private Map<K, T> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public Set<java.util.Map.Entry<K, T>> entrySet() {
        return map.entrySet();
    }
    ...
}
```

The package `org.abego.util` defines the default nullness to be `@NonNull`:

```
@org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNullByDefault
package org.abego.util;
```

The only way I found to get rid of the error was to 'remove the default nullness annotation' for `entrySet` using an `@NonNullByDefault({})` annotation:

```
package org.abego.util;
...
import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNullByDefault;

public abstract class MyMap<K, T> implements Map<K, T> {
    ...
    @Override
    @NonNullByDefault({})
    public Set<java.util.Map.Entry<K, T>> entrySet() {
        return map.entrySet();
    }
    ...
}
```

While this does work I am wondering if this is the *correct* way to fix the error.

(I am using Eclipse 4.5 (Mars) and jdk1.8.0_60.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to override this method:

```
Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet();
```

with a method whose effective signature is

```
@NonNull Set<@NonNull Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet();
```

This is an incompatible override as can be demonstrated via this caller:

```
Set<Map.Entry<Foo,Bar>> entries = someMap.entrySet();
entries.add(null);
```

If `someMap` has type `MyMap` then the element type of `entries` is `@NonNull`, but the contract of `java.util.Map.entrySet()` promises a `Set` where `null` elements are tolerated (set has not specified nullness of its elements). Mixing both contracts (with `@NonNull` and unspecified) on the same object `entries` will break clients that assume non-null elements.

Looking at the Javadoc of `entrySet()`, it should however be safe to assume that `Map.entrySet()` will **always** return a `Set` with non-null elements. Hence, the root of the problem is in the fact, that `java.util.Map.entrySet()` has no null annotations.

Since Eclipse Mars, this can be overcome by way of [external null annotations](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_external_null_annotations.htm?cp=1_3_9_2). You can tell the compiler that the return type of `Map.entrySet()` is in fact `@NonNull Set<@NonNull Map.Entry<K,V>>`, either by applying the [Annotate command](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.5/jdt.php#annotate-command) in the IDE, or by putting the following snippet into a file `java/util/Map.eea` inside a directory that has been [configured as the location for external annotations](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_external_null_annotations.htm?cp=1_3_9_2_1#configure) for the JRE:

```
class java/util/Map

entrySet
 ()Ljava/util/Set<Ljava/util/Map$Entry<TK;TV;>;>;
 ()L1java/util/Set<L1java/util/Map$Entry<TK;TV;>;>;
```

With such external annotations in place your program will be accepted by JDT's null analysis.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue. I am now using the external null annotation feature for other issues I ran into. Mainly this means adding annotations to JRE methods to "my" external annotations files. As I am probably not the only one running into issues like this I am wondering if there is already some place (like a Git repo or so) that holds the external annotation files for e.g. the Java 1.8 JRE.

Comment: As per https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Null_Analysis/External_Annotations#Collecting_annotations what you request is on our roadmap indeed. First thing on the agenda: knowing that others have produced annotation stub-jars for JRE, Eclipse shall offer a wizard for importing those annotations from jar to our textual format. More to come later...